# Add section comments to my Details view

Tags: asp.net-core

in my View I have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="Comment" method="post">
        <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label"></label>
        <textarea asp-for="Comment.Content" class="form-control" placeholder="Add comment!"></textarea>
        <span asp-validation-for="Comment.Content" class="text-danger"></span>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="Add comment" class="btn btn-default" />
```

This is in my Details View. Now I want to add comment to my model

```
    public class TicketCommentViewModel
{
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
}
```

and Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Comment(TicketCommentViewModel model)
    {
                    var ticket = await _context.Tickets.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.TicketId == model.Ticket.TicketId);
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if(ticket == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        model.Comment.SendTime = DateTime.Now;
        model.Comment.TicketID = ticket.TicketId;
        model.Comment.Ticket = ticket;
        model.Comment.UserId = user.Id;
        model.Comment.User = user;
        _context.Comments.Add(model.Comment);
        ticket.Comments = await _context.Comments.ToListAsync();
        return View();
    }
```

I have problem with this -> How to go from first code (add Comment) to Controller, and add my Comment to DB.
Can someone help me with that ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what is the problem but I guess that when you click submit your data is not submitted. This is because your submit button is outside the `<form>.` Try move the submit button inside the `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

```
//Two action methods in the controller      
public ActionResult AddComment(int PageId, string name, string email, string comment)
            {
                Comment comment = new Comment()
                {
                    PageID = PageId,
                    Name = name,                    
                    Email = email,
                    Comment = comment,                    
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now
                };
                DbContext.Add(jobOffer);

                return PartialView("ShowComments", DbContext.Where(c=> c.pageID == PageId));
            }

            public ActionResult ShowComments(int PageId)
            {           
                return PartialView(DbContext.Where(c=> c.pageID == PageId));
            }



//Add the script after the comment div in the View

 <script>
            function addComment() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Comment/AddComment/"+@Model.PageID,
                    type: "Get",
                    data: {
                        name: $("#txtName").val(), email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
    comment : $("#txtComment").val() }
                }).done(function(result) {

                    $("#offerList").html(result);
                    $("#txtName").val("");
                    $("#txtEmail").val("");
                    $("#txtComment").val("");
                });
            }
            </script>
```